# React FontAwesome - problem on loading fa-thin

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

Trying to use FontAwesome icons on React but I am having some issues on importing the files correctly.

First I installed some dependencies and I am now able to import the component as follow

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
```

and use it (succesfully) as

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
```

However, the icon I would like to use is this one ( [icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/trash?s=light&f=classic) ) but I can't seem to be able to actually import it. If I try `import { faThin } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";` it doesn't work and if I try `import { faThin } from "@fortawesome/free-thin-svg-icons";` it doesn't neither.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That font is part of the light  package `(fa-light fa-trash)`, so you will need:

`@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons`

and a subscription to pro.